# Pay per impression adsense provider

Tags: google-adsense

I am searching for a good adsense provider who pays per impression. 
please suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like [AdBrite](http://www.adbrite.com/)?

Comment: is there adbrite only? do you know more. i dint find it more effective

Comment: I really don't know other per-impression providers but you can also check http://www.cpalead.com/, http://www.bidvertiser.com/, http://www.httpool.com/.